# What's the static flow control in GLSL?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, flow-control

[PowerVR documentation from Imagination](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/docs/POWERVR%20SGX.OpenGL%20ES%202.0%20Application%20Development%20Recommendations.1.8f.External.pdf) says there's *static flow control*. (7.9 Flow Contro)

What's the static flow control? Does it mean compiler preprocessor like `#if...#endif`? And they're saying,

```
Static flow control can be used to combine many shaders into one big shader.
```

and what does this mean? Can I instantiate many variants of shaders from one source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the text earlier in 7.9:

> When conditional execution depends on the value of a uniform variable,
>   this is called static flow control

So you'd have one shader that made a branch decision based on a uniform. That would be static flow control.

What they're trying to tell you is that setting uniforms can dynamically reprogram shaders — the compiled code will be patched with the new uniform values rather than those values being looked up every time the shader runs. So the costs for accessing uniforms within a shader are the same as for using constants and the costs for setting uniforms outside the shader are probably greater than you'd guess.

Comment: Note that this is *hardware specific*. That's how their particular piece of hardware works.

Comment: Indeed, with the caveat that all Apple devices use PowerVR GPUs so if iOS is your target then you can optimise for PowerVR without any concerns. They're reasonably common in Android land but you also see a lot of Nvidia Tegras and Broadcom parts that may well act very differently.